# Which nonlinear regression to choose for S shaped residuals (sine wave curve)

Tags: r, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am trying to statistically analyze time series data of two variables (overall there are 20 variables I want to regress with my independent variable). In the beginning I tried to use a regular lm function:

```
lm_par1 <- lm(rm_SWI_010~Parrot_cal, data=wheat_new)
summary(lm_par1)
```

My residuals however look S shaped in a nonlinear pattern like a sine wave curve.
e.g. Almost all of my residuals look sine curved.

An idea was to generate the rollmean between 2 to 7 days of my dependent variable, in order to reduce the noise of the sine shape.
Nevertheless the sine curved line is still similarly visible.

```
n=7
wheat_new[, aux:=c(0, rep(1:(.N-1)%/%n))]
wheat_new[, rm_SWI_010:=mean(SWI_010, na.rm=T), by=.(aux)][, aux:=NULL]
```

Since the rollmean lead to nowhere I am contemplating of using nonlinear regression to check if it solves my residual issue.
So far I have the following code:

```r
model <- drm(SWI_005 ~ Parrot_cal, fct = MM.2(),
             data = wheat_new)
summary(model)
```

or

```r
yy <- nls(SWI_005~c*Parrot_cal^z, data=wheat_new,
       start= c(c=14, z=.27))
summary(yy)
```

Both codes work, however I am not able to check my residuals as used with the lm function:

```r
wheat_new[, res_par1:yy$residuals]

res_par1 <-ggplot(wheat_new, aes(x=date, y=res_par1))+
  geom_point(colour='blue', size=2.2, alpha=0.5)+
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%b'), date_breaks = '1 month') +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(0), size=0.75, color='black', linetype='dashed') +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', size=1, colour='black', linetype = 'dashed', alpha=0.2)+
  ylab('Residuals')+xlab('Date') +
  labs(title=('Residual Plot'))
res_par1 <- res_par1 + theme_bw(base_family='Playfair', base_size = 15, base_rect_size = 1) 
res_par1
```

Now I am looking for ideas concerning the right choice of nonlinear regression as well as how to check for residuals. One important fact to mention is, that in nature there is no value below the wilting point and none above field capacity (WP = 9 vol % and FC = 23 vol % in my case).
The data features different sensors of soil moisture.

```
     Date        ASS_TOP SWI_001 SWI_005 SWI_010 B1_005 B1_015 Precip B2_005 B2_015 B3_005 B3_015  SMAP Parrot_cal
 1: 04.04.2019   12.21   13.02   13.42   13.96    9.0    9.6    0.0    9.0    9.6    8.5    9.5    NA       14.8
 2: 05.04.2019   12.99   14.77   13.76   14.08    8.7    9.6    1.9    8.7    9.6    9.8    9.5 14.89       14.7
 3: 06.04.2019   12.73   13.76   13.66   14.02    9.0    9.6    0.5    9.0    9.6    9.9    9.5    NA       14.8
 4: 07.04.2019   12.08   13.14   13.52   13.91    8.7    9.6    0.0    8.7    9.6    9.6    9.5    NA       14.7
 5: 08.04.2019   11.69   13.70   13.61   13.92    8.7    9.6    0.0    8.7    9.6    9.6    9.5 14.58       14.7
 6: 09.04.2019   11.17   12.72   13.30   13.72    8.7    9.6    0.0    8.7    9.6    9.6    9.5    NA       14.6
 7: 10.04.2019   12.99   13.72   13.50   13.78    9.7    9.6    2.4    9.7    9.6   10.6    9.5    NA       14.5
 8: 11.04.2019   12.34   13.22   13.41   13.71    9.5    9.6    0.0    9.5    9.6    9.5    9.5 14.32       14.5
 9: 12.04.2019   11.82   12.94   13.29   13.62    9.2    9.6    0.0    9.2    9.6    9.2    9.5    NA       14.4
10: 13.04.2019   11.43   12.71   13.16   13.52    9.1    9.6    0.0    9.1    9.6    9.1    9.5    NA       14.4
11: 14.04.2019   11.30   12.80   13.11   13.46    8.9    9.6    0.0    8.9    9.6    8.9    9.5 13.98       14.3
12: 15.04.2019   11.04   12.73   13.03   13.39    8.7    9.6    0.0    8.7    9.6    8.6    9.5    NA       14.3
13: 16.04.2019   10.78   12.12   12.82   13.25    8.4    9.6    0.0    8.4    9.6    8.4    9.5    NA        9.9
14: 19.04.2019   10.26   12.73   12.75   13.10    7.7    9.6    0.0    7.7    9.6    7.5    9.5    NA       11.4
15: 20.04.2019   10.26   13.03   12.86   13.12    7.5    9.6    0.0    7.5    9.6    7.5    9.5 13.20       14.7
16: 21.04.2019   10.13   12.11   12.62   12.98    7.4    9.6    0.0    7.4    9.6    7.5    9.5    NA       14.6
17: 22.04.2019   10.13   12.63   12.67   12.96    7.4    9.6    0.0    7.4    9.6    7.5    9.5    NA       14.5
18: 23.04.2019   11.82   13.05   12.73   12.96    8.6    9.6    1.3    8.6    9.6    8.6    9.5 13.00       14.4
19: 24.04.2019   11.17   12.70   12.69   12.92    8.3    9.6    0.0    8.3    9.6    8.2    9.5    NA       14.4
20: 25.04.2019   10.78   12.87   12.73   12.92    7.9    9.6    0.0    8.0    9.6    7.8    9.5    NA       14.5
21: 26.04.2019   10.39   12.29   12.60   12.83    7.5    9.6    0.0    7.6    9.6    7.5    9.5 12.77       14.4
22: 27.04.2019   10.26   11.77   12.39   12.70    7.4    9.6    0.0    7.4    9.6    7.5    9.5    NA       14.2
23: 28.04.2019   10.13   11.47   12.20   12.57    7.4    9.6    0.0    7.4    9.6    7.5    9.5    NA       14.1
24: 29.04.2019   10.78   12.78   12.46   12.68    8.4    9.6    1.1    8.4    9.6    8.4    9.5 13.20       14.1
25: 30.04.2019   18.32   15.99   13.47   13.19   19.9    9.6   12.3   19.9    9.6   20.0    9.5    NA       17.2
26: 01.05.2019   16.63   14.49   13.53   13.25   15.7    9.6    0.0   15.7    9.6   15.8    9.5    NA       19.8
27: 02.05.2019   14.68   13.78   13.50   13.26   11.5    9.6    0.0   11.5    9.6   12.1    9.5 13.54       18.4
28: 03.05.2019   20.14   15.44   14.03   13.56   14.4    9.6    4.7   14.3    9.6   15.0    9.5    NA       20.1
29: 04.05.2019   21.44   15.68   14.33   13.76   16.2    9.6    3.2   16.2    9.6   16.8    9.5    NA       20.5
30: 05.05.2019   23.00   16.83   14.70   13.97   21.0    9.6    5.0   20.9    9.6   21.6    9.5 14.41       23.0
31: 06.05.2019   22.09   15.67   14.80   14.09   20.1    9.6    0.2   20.0    9.6   20.7    9.5    NA       22.7
32: 07.05.2019   20.79   14.22   14.56   14.04   18.0    9.6    0.0   18.0    9.6   18.7    9.5    NA       21.9
33: 08.05.2019   19.10   13.19   14.21   13.91   15.4    9.6    0.0   15.3    9.6   16.2    9.5 14.52       21.1
34: 09.05.2019   21.18   15.05   14.64   14.17   17.7    9.6    4.0   17.6    9.6   18.5    9.5    NA       21.2
35: 10.05.2019   19.36   14.28   14.52   14.15   14.7    9.6    0.8   14.6    9.6   15.6    9.5    NA       21.2
36: 11.05.2019   23.00   15.32   14.72   14.29   21.4    9.6    9.5   21.3    9.6   22.3    9.5 15.07       21.0
37: 12.05.2019   23.00   16.47   15.13   14.55   21.8    9.6    1.6   21.7    9.6   22.7    9.5    NA       22.8
38: 13.05.2019   22.22   15.53   15.18   14.66   20.1    9.6    0.3   20.0    9.6   21.1    9.5    NA       22.5
39: 14.05.2019   23.00   16.02   15.31   14.77   20.9    9.6    1.9   20.8    9.6   21.8    9.5 15.66       22.1
40: 15.05.2019   23.00   17.05   15.66   15.00   23.8    9.6    3.3   23.7    9.6   24.7    9.5    NA       22.9
41: 16.05.2019   23.00   17.03   15.91   15.20   26.3   11.3    5.7   26.3   11.2   28.9    9.5    NA       23.2
42: 17.05.2019   21.44   15.46   15.68   15.14   19.4   15.3    0.0   19.4   15.2   26.1    9.5 16.08       22.3
43: 18.05.2019   20.01   14.60   15.40   15.05   16.4   15.3    0.0   16.4   15.2   23.1    9.5    NA       21.7
44: 19.05.2019   18.71   14.20   15.15   14.95   13.7   15.3    0.0   13.7   15.2   20.4    9.5    NA       21.1
45: 20.05.2019   22.87   15.73   15.45   15.13   18.4   15.3    7.4   18.4   15.2   25.1    9.5 16.54       22.0
46: 21.05.2019   22.74   15.13   15.36   15.11   17.4   15.3    0.8   17.4   15.2   24.1    9.5    NA       22.0
47: 22.05.2019   23.00   17.64   16.00   15.47   19.4   15.3    3.3   19.3   15.2   26.1    9.5    NA       22.5
48: 23.05.2019   21.70   16.31   15.93   15.49   17.2   15.3    0.0   17.2   15.2   24.0    9.5 17.36       22.6
49: 24.05.2019   19.75   14.77   15.59   15.35   12.7   15.3    0.0   12.6   15.2   19.5    9.5    NA       21.9
50: 25.05.2019   17.93   13.98   15.23   15.18    9.5   15.3    0.0    8.9   15.2   15.4    9.5    NA       21.1
51: 26.05.2019   16.24   13.05   14.76   14.94    9.3   12.6    0.0    8.7   12.0   11.9    9.5 17.06       20.3
52: 27.05.2019   16.37   14.59   14.83   14.96    9.1   12.6    1.5    9.5   10.7   11.8    9.5    NA       19.8
53: 28.05.2019   21.96   17.32   15.60   15.35   19.9   12.6   12.0   20.4   10.7   22.7    9.5    NA       21.7
54: 29.05.2019   22.87   16.79   15.80   15.48   20.4   12.6    1.5   20.9   10.7   23.2    9.5 18.49       22.5
55: 30.05.2019   23.00   16.19   15.82   15.53   22.6   12.6    3.4   23.0   10.7   25.3    9.5    NA       22.8
56: 31.05.2019   21.18   15.06   15.61   15.45   18.0   13.1    0.0   18.0   11.6   21.3    9.5    NA       22.3
57: 01.06.2019   18.97   14.10   15.24   15.27   13.6   13.1    0.0   13.6   11.6   16.9    9.5 18.19       21.5
58: 02.06.2019   16.76   13.56   14.89   15.08    9.6   13.1    0.0    9.5   11.6   12.0    9.5    NA       20.5
59: 03.06.2019   14.81   12.97   14.49   14.86    9.3   10.4    0.0    9.3    8.4    9.4    9.5    NA       19.6
60: 04.06.2019   12.86   12.83   14.19   14.66    9.1    9.3    0.0    9.1    8.4    9.1    9.5 17.27       18.6
61: 05.06.2019   11.69   12.88   13.97   14.51    8.9    9.3    0.0    8.9    8.4    8.8    9.5    NA       17.6
62: 06.06.2019   11.17   12.43   13.62   14.27    8.7    9.3    0.0    8.8    8.4    8.6    9.5    NA       17.1
63: 07.06.2019   16.24   13.25   13.66   14.23   12.3    9.3    7.7   12.3    8.4   12.3    9.5 17.22       18.1
64: 08.06.2019   13.77   13.10   13.58   14.14    9.8    9.3    0.0    9.7    8.4   10.0    9.5    NA       17.5
65: 09.06.2019   12.08   12.78   13.40   13.99    9.6    9.3    0.0    9.4    8.4    9.7    9.5    NA       16.7
66: 10.06.2019   11.17   12.88   13.32   13.89    9.3    9.3    0.0    9.2    8.4    9.4    9.5 16.37       16.1
67: 11.06.2019   10.65   13.04   13.27   13.79    9.0    9.3    0.0    8.9    8.4    9.0    9.5    NA       15.6
68: 12.06.2019   10.26   13.38   13.35   13.78    8.6    9.3    0.0    8.6    8.4    8.6    9.5    NA       15.1
69: 13.06.2019   10.13   12.98   13.25   13.69    8.3    9.3    0.0    8.3    8.4    8.3    9.5 15.64       14.9
70: 14.06.2019   10.13   13.17   13.24   13.65    8.0    9.3    0.0    8.0    8.4    7.9    9.5    NA       14.7
71: 15.06.2019   10.00   13.45   13.30   13.64    7.6    9.3    0.0    7.7    8.4    7.5    9.5    NA       14.5
72: 16.06.2019   10.00   13.01   13.24   13.58    8.5    9.3    1.2    8.6    8.4    8.2    9.5 14.99       14.4
73: 17.06.2019   10.00   13.24   13.27   13.57    8.2    9.3    0.0    8.3    8.4    7.9    9.5    NA       14.3
74: 18.06.2019   10.00   12.71   13.12   13.46    7.8    9.3    0.0    7.9    8.4    7.5    9.5    NA       14.2
75: 19.06.2019   10.65   13.28   13.21   13.48    8.4    9.3    1.0    8.6    8.4    8.0    9.5 14.50       14.1
76: 20.06.2019   10.39   13.13   13.19   13.44    8.4    9.3    0.2    8.6    8.4    8.0    9.5    NA       14.0
77: 21.06.2019   10.26   12.94   13.13   13.39    8.4    9.3    0.1    8.6    8.4    8.0    9.5    NA       13.9
78: 22.06.2019   10.13   14.04   13.40   13.50    8.6    9.3    0.5    8.8    8.4    8.1    9.5 14.64       13.8
79: 23.06.2019   13.38   15.80   14.03   13.82   11.8    9.3    4.9   11.9    8.4   12.0    9.5    NA       13.9
80: 24.06.2019   11.82   14.83   14.08   13.87   10.1    9.3    0.0   10.1    8.4   10.7    9.5    NA       14.0
81: 25.06.2019   11.04   13.72   13.90   13.79    9.6    9.3    0.0    9.6    8.4   10.0    9.5 14.33       13.9
82: 26.06.2019   10.52   13.44   13.80   13.75    8.9    9.3    0.0    9.0    8.4    9.1    9.5    NA       13.8
83: 27.06.2019   10.26   13.51   13.76   13.74    8.2    9.3    0.0    8.3    8.4    8.2    9.5    NA       13.7
84: 28.06.2019   10.13   12.45   13.42   13.56    7.5    9.3    0.0    7.6    8.4    7.4    9.5 13.82       13.5
85: 29.06.2019   10.13   12.19   13.18   13.43    6.8    9.3    0.0    7.0    8.4    6.7    9.5    NA       13.4
86: 30.06.2019   10.00   12.08   12.96   13.29    6.0    9.3    0.0    6.2    8.4    6.7    9.5    NA       13.3
87: 01.07.2019   13.51   13.86   13.62   13.61    8.0    9.3    2.8    8.2    8.4    8.5    9.5 13.54       13.2
88: 02.07.2019   12.47   13.51   13.53   13.55    8.0    9.3    0.1    8.2    8.4    8.5    9.5    NA       13.1
89: 03.07.2019   11.56   12.96   13.38   13.46    7.9    9.3    0.0    8.2    8.4    8.4    9.5    NA       13.1
90: 04.07.2019   11.04   12.82   13.29   13.41    7.9    9.3    0.0    8.2    8.4    8.4    9.5 13.20       13.1
91: 05.07.2019   10.65   12.43   13.13   13.31    7.9    9.3    0.0    8.1    8.4    8.4    9.5    NA       12.7
```

Comment: The S-shaped residuals are very likely due to autocorrelation - try e.g. running a model with `arx` from the `gets` package, which outputs a test for autocorrelation at the bottom. you could also use the `acf` command to check the dependent variable for autocorrelation like so: `acf(wheat_new$rm_SWI_010)`

Comment: @MoritzSchwarz Thanks for pointing in the right direction. I used the code you provided and it works well. However, I am not on top of my game regarding statistics. 
What tells me the acf plot in the end? I see that there is a downtrend in my residuals. 
Is there a solution to reduce the sine wave curve?
In the end I suppose, that the response of my dependent sensor lags somewhat behind which leads to the sine wave.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck The residuals from my initial lm function are being plotted against date. Thats featured in the smaple code above in the ggplot which works. However, the residuals for the non-linear regression I cannot plot. That would be the question if there is a solution or different method to generate residuals with non-linear regressions

Answer (score 1):

Using wheat shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, the residuals vs. time look more random (see plot at end) if a lag is added.  Note that the lag term is significant at the 0.1% level, i.e. it is highly significant.

Regarding the code, dyn will ensure that the series are aligned. Be sure that dplyr is not loaded since dplyr clobbers R's lag generic.

Regarding plotting residuals from an nls fit it can be done in the same way as for lm:  plot(resid(nls(...))) .

```
library(dyn)

wheat.z <- zoo(wheat)
fm <- dyn$lm(SWI_010 ~ Parrot_cal + lag(SWI_010, -1), wheat.z)
plot(resid(fm), type = "p")
anova(fm)
```

giving:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: SWI_010
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Parrot_cal        1 35.315  35.315  2157.1 < 2.2e-16 ***
lag(SWI_010, -1)  1 18.052  18.052  1102.6 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals        87  1.424   0.016                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
wheat <- structure(list(Parrot_cal = c(14.8, 14.7, 14.8, 14.7, 14.7, 14.6, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.4, 14.4, 14.3, 14.3, 9.9, 11.4, 14.7, 14.6, 14.5, 
14.4, 14.4, 14.5, 14.4, 14.2, 14.1, 14.1, 17.2, 19.8, 18.4, 20.1, 
20.5, 23, 22.7, 21.9, 21.1, 21.2, 21.2, 21, 22.8, 22.5, 22.1, 
22.9, 23.2, 22.3, 21.7, 21.1, 22, 22, 22.5, 22.6, 21.9, 21.1, 
20.3, 19.8, 21.7, 22.5, 22.8, 22.3, 21.5, 20.5, 19.6, 18.6, 17.6, 
17.1, 18.1, 17.5, 16.7, 16.1, 15.6, 15.1, 14.9, 14.7, 14.5, 14.4, 
14.3, 14.2, 14.1, 14, 13.9, 13.8, 13.9, 14, 13.9, 13.8, 13.7, 
13.5, 13.4, 13.3, 13.2, 13.1, 13.1, 13.1, 12.7), SWI_010 = c(13.96, 
14.08, 14.02, 13.91, 13.92, 13.72, 13.78, 13.71, 13.62, 13.52, 
13.46, 13.39, 13.25, 13.1, 13.12, 12.98, 12.96, 12.96, 12.92, 
12.92, 12.83, 12.7, 12.57, 12.68, 13.19, 13.25, 13.26, 13.56, 
13.76, 13.97, 14.09, 14.04, 13.91, 14.17, 14.15, 14.29, 14.55, 
14.66, 14.77, 15, 15.2, 15.14, 15.05, 14.95, 15.13, 15.11, 15.47, 
15.49, 15.35, 15.18, 14.94, 14.96, 15.35, 15.48, 15.53, 15.45, 
15.27, 15.08, 14.86, 14.66, 14.51, 14.27, 14.23, 14.14, 13.99, 
13.89, 13.79, 13.78, 13.69, 13.65, 13.64, 13.58, 13.57, 13.46, 
13.48, 13.44, 13.39, 13.5, 13.82, 13.87, 13.79, 13.75, 13.74, 
13.56, 13.43, 13.29, 13.61, 13.55, 13.46, 13.41, 13.31)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-91L))
```